# Delphi 10.2 AsynchPro x32 / x64

Tags: delphi

Установил AsynchPro в Delphi 10.2, все компоненты появились на панели инструментов.  Но при наведении курсора всплывает подсказка с информацией и компоненте, где указано, что все APRO компоненты поддерживаются только для 32-bit Windows. Как сделать, чтобы и для 64-bit тоже поддерживались?

a407_d140.bdl

Comment: В природе не существует такой версии как *Delphi XE10*. Есть Delphi XE (первая в линейке) и есть Delphi 10.2. [Wiki в помощь: Delphi (среда разработки)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8))

Answer (score 4):

В документации к либе написано:

> Async Professional is a comprehensive communications toolkit for
>   Embarcadero/CodeGear Delphi for win32 targets.

т.е. разработчик вам прямым текстом говорит, что поддерживается только 32-х битная платформа.

Соответственно, на ваш вопрос *"Как сделать, чтобы и для 64-bit тоже поддерживались?"* можно дать такой ответ (но боюсь, он вам не очень понравится):

**Взять сорцы (благо, они доступны) и адаптировать компонент для поддержки x64 и Delphi 10.xx**

Comment: У меня Embarcadero Delphi 10.2. Да насчет XE попутал... Все ее компоненты поддерживаются для обоих платформ.

Comment: А можете тогда дать наводку - что нужно править в сорсах для x64?

Comment: @AVM Наводки дать могу: [раз](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Converting_32-bit_Delphi_Applications_to_64-bit_Windows), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568685/how-to-also-prepare-for-64-bits-when-migrating-to-delphi-2010-and-unicode), [три](https://habrahabr.ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/80936/)